# Preimage of a smooth function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis

Suppose we are given a smooth function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and some number $c$. What can be said about the preimage $f^{-1}(c)$.

There's the theorem on regular preimages, asserting that if $\nabla f$ is nowhere vanishing on $M=f^{-1}(c),$
then $M$ is a smooth submanifold of dimension $n-1$.

But now lets assume that one does not have a regular preimage. Can one say anything about the preimage here (except what would already follow from continuity), or is this a hopeless case?

Comment: The preimage $f^{-1}(c)$ is of course closed but can be rather wild. For instance, for $n=1$, an arbitrary closed subset in $\mathbb R$ has such a form.

Comment: If you mean in the case of $n=1$, let $M=f^{-1}(0)$, where $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is $C^\infty$.Then the complement of $M$ is given by $f^2(x)>0$ $\dots$

Comment: Well, the OP is changing his/her question more quickly than I am typing. I give up.

Comment: Anyway, the case is hopeless. The zero set of a $C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ can be any closed set, as Sasha said already (there is nothing special about dimension $1$ here). Should we close?

Comment: @fedja I guess, not many professionals know your answer. In this sense, the question is helpful.

Comment: @Sasha, why don't you write your proof in 1d, if my guess about it is correct, it will extend to higher dimensions, I think you are just missing the covering dimension argument.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, the level sets can in general be very wild. However, if at every point of the level set the function locally looks like a polynomial (unfortunately, I'm not sure how to phrase such a condition precisely), then the singularity of the level set at each point might look like the singularity of the algebraic variety defined by the corresponding polynomial. Then you get something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_theory#Singularities_in_algebraic_geometry

Comment: @Misha Sure! I do not do so because this is an exercise in a russian book (published by Moscow Independent University) that I am translating now (into portugues), and I would like my students to solve it themselves

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link to the quoted result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not mean to spoil the exercise, but  note that if $\phi$ is any  smooth function  on a Banach space $E$, with bounded derivatives of any order (say $\|D^j\phi\|_\infty < \infty$ for any $j\ge0$), then $f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k^k \phi\big(\frac{x-a_k}{d_k} \big)$ certainly defines a smooth function for any choice of a sequence of vectors $ a_k\in  E$, and of numbers $0 < d_k \le 1/2$. To be able to make the zero-set of $f$ whatever closed set $C\subset E$ you like, just requires $E$ to be separable, and possess a smooth $\phi$ with bounded derivatives and bounded support (and  non-zero, of course, hence wlog also non-negative).

Comment: Nice! (For $n=1$, the idea was similar, but your exposition is great and does not look as spoiling.)